# spring-cloud version Hoxton.SR6 caused an issues for Vault integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, hashicorp-vault

Recently upgraded spring-cloud version to Hoxton.SR6 started getting below error on vault integration which is working with Greenwich.SR6

pom.xml

```
<spring.boot.version>2.3.2.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
```

error message

```
org.springframework.vault.VaultException: Status 403 Forbidden [secret/crypto/acceptance]: 1 error occurred:
    * permission denied

; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: [{"errors":["1 error occurred:\n\t* permission denied\n\n"]}
]
```

Comment: Issue Raised https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/issues/209

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to Spring boot to 2.3.3 and Spring Cloud to Hoxton.SR7 resolved worked fine with hashicorp vault.

```
<spring.boot.version>2.3.3.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR7</spring-cloud.version>
```